# Is there a way to disable a specific CPU core in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, affinity

After some experimentation with stress testing tools, I have determined that one specific core on my system has issues with AVX/AVX2 instructions, and I wish to completely disable that core.  There is no bios option in my system to do this.  Is there any way to do this in Windows, or at the very least, change the default affinity mask to not include it?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a setting. Which core index (of how many cores in total) is it? Maybe the CPU count limit could be enough to achieve what you want.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately its one of the cores in the middle of the index.

Comment: What are your computer and CPU models?